# Python C Extension How to test reference counting and memory leaks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

Is there an idiomatic way to test a python C extension such that you can have high confidence that your reference counting is correct and that you will not have any memory leaks?

I currently just uncomment some `printf` statements in my deallocator functions, and then type up a variety of situations by hand to prove to myself that my `Py_INCREF`'s and `Py_DECREF`'s are correct- that the reference counts on objects have decreffed to 0 and the deallocator was called when expected. I'm looking for a way to automate this in the regression tests.

For example, say you have a C type called `Foo` with a Python wrapper called `PyFoo`. A `Foo` can have many children; each child may belong to only one parent. When a child's reference count goes out of scope, it should not free the associated C type - rather it should just decrement the parent. When the parent's reference count goes to 0, it should be responsible for freeing the associated C type

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD

    Foo *wrapped_foo;
    PyObject *parent;
} PyFoo;

/*
* Add a child to a parent, PY_INCREF the parent
* /
static void PyFoo_push(PyFoo *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)
{
    int field = 0;
    PyFoo *child = NULL;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iO!", &field, &FooType, &child)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Foo_push(self->foo, field, child->foo);

    child->parent = self;
    Py_INCREF(self);
}

static void PyFoo_dealloc(PyFoo *self)
{
    if (self->parent) {
        printf("I'm a child, decreffing my parent\n");
        Py_XDECREF(self->parent);
    } else {
        printf("I'm a parent, freeing my wrapped foo\n");
        Foo_destroy(self->foo);
    }
}
```

Now in Python, I would write something like the following to test it works:

```
>>> parent = Foo()
>>> child = Foo()
>>> parent['ABC'] = child
>>> del child
I'm a child, decreffing my parent
>>> del parent
I'm a parent, freeing my wrapped foo

>>> parent = Foo()
>>> child = Foo()
>>> parent['ABC'] = child
>>> del parent
>>> del child
I'm a child, decreffing my parent
I'm a parent, freeing my wrapped foo
```

I've also exposed a function to return the Py_REFCNT value of a PyFoo object back into Python. I can write some tests with this but it is not that great because I don't really want to expose this as a private function in my library, and it also doesn't account for when the reference account drops to 0.

Comment: Just for the last bit of your question [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) saves you having to wrap `Py_REFCNT`

Comment: @DavidW Nice, thanks.

Comment: Also look into module `gc` and in particular use `gc.collect()` before checking the ref-counts. Personally I find it useful to have a build of the python interpreter with the flags `--with-address-sanitizer --with-pydebug` handed to `configure`, then test with that. It will find leaks, some ref-count problems, and some missing error messages. For testing directly, I like add my own counters to the object in debug mode only.

Comment: @WimLavrijsen in my code, after I for example add a child to a parent, the C code should have called Py_INCREF; lifewise after removing a child from a parent, the C code should have called Py_DECREF; shouldn't I be able to immediately check the ref-count without calling `gc.collect()` in this case? When would I want to call `gc.collect()` before checking the refcount?

Comment: @WimLavrijsen It would be best to have two interpreters, one compiled with --with-address-sanitizer --with-pydebug that I use only for my tests, and one compiled without these flags to be used in production - is that right?

Comment: Yes, in this simple case `gc.collect()` isn't needed, but within a test harness I always call it as the harness may evaluate the statements differently (e.g. in order to be able to re-run them) or the test may run on pypy, etc. Besides breaking cycles, `collect` will also run finalizers, which may trigger further cleanup (esp. again in a test harness). Also yes, I use separate interpreter builds and run all tests on each. Esp. the `--with-pydebug` has caught some pretty odd stuff that would have costed me lot more time to solve otherwise.